# Can not understand Django and mixin behaviour

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I have the following hierarchy of classes:

```
class ProfileUpdateView( UpdateView, LoggerMixin ):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...
        return context
```

UpdateView is in fact django.views.generic.UpdateView

```
class EventViewMixin(object):
    template_name = ...
    model = Event
    form_class = ...

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.success_url + str(self.object.id)
```

Class UpdateEventView mixes ProfileUpdateView and EventViewMixin

```
class UpdateEventView(ProfileUpdateView, EventViewMixin):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        return super(UpdateEventView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The problem in that for some reason the field "model=Event" is not visible to the framework when 
it tries to use UpdateEventView. So I get the error:

UpdateEventView is missing a queryset. Define UpdateEventView.model, UpdateEventView.queryset, or override UpdateEventView.get_object().

What am I missing?

DISCLAIMER: I'm sort of a newbie to Python/Django.

Comment: Someone predicted this'd happen: http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/08/23/class-based-views.html :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my question in sort of dumb ... 
The problem is in the order of the mixins:

```
class UpdateEventView(ProfileUpdateView, EventViewMixin):
    ....
```

must be replaced with:

```
class UpdateEventView( EventViewMixin, ProfileUpdateView ):
```

This is because ProfileUpdateView has in its inheritance tree a field "model=None",
and if ProfileUpdateView is on the first position in the that is the value that 
will be considered. If EventViewMixin comes first, then the correct value is taken.